# scroll bar for a table cell

Tags: html, scrollbar, html-table

Is there a way to add a scroll bar to a 'td' tag?
I have a dynamic content inside a 'td' tag. I want the 'td' to be of fixed size and if the content becomes larger than the 'td' size, I want a scroll bar to appear only on that particular cell. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use the jquery j[scrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) for that.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

The easiest way is to put inside your cell a div filling it and set its `overflow` style property.

**CSS :**

```
div.scrollable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<td><div class=scrollable>
    Some content with a scrollbar if it's too big for the cell
</div></td>
```

If you want the scrollbar to be always visible, even when the content isn't cropped, replace `auto` with `scroll` in the CSS.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/jatexeke/1)

Comment: Is it possible to add a scrollbar to all td cells in a table row except the first and last cells in the same row?

Comment: I also needed `table-layout: fixed;` to get it to work.

Answer (score 18):

```
<table  width ="400" >
    <tr>
        <td >
            <div style="width:100%; max-height:300px; overflow:auto">Your content here 
             </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7T2S4/1/

Hope this helps

Comment: you code also fails: http://jsfiddle.net/7T2S4/78/ because you've made a very very specific example that works, doesn't mean it's a good solution.

Comment: vsync, I went to that page with FF new version in 2016, and it seems to work fine. Maybe you had "old" browser issues. An important point, a minimal requirement, is that the div apparently needs to have "height" attribute set in some way in addition to the "overflow:auto".

Comment: It works thank you very much. I had trouble to find a valid solution.

Comment: i find many solution but only this one works ..thank you so much Parag

Comment: This one works well

Answer (score 5):

You should need to provide either "height" Or "width" of div element, So that it would be scroll accordingly. 
for example you want to apply Scroll Vertically(Y-axis):-

```
<td><div class="scrollable">
    Some content with a scrollbar if it's not fit in your customized container
</div></td>

div.scrollable
{
width:100%;
height: 100px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow-y: scroll
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I believe but was finding that a scrolling div was still expanding across my page, so had to combine with a fixed table-layout.

```css
    #input, #output {
        font:10px 'Lucida Console', 'courier new', monospace;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        overflow:auto;
        border:1px inset;
        padding:2px;
        background-color:#fff;
        white-space:pre;
    }
    table {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
        cellspacing:0;
        cellpadding:0;
    }
```

```html
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="50%"">
                    <div id="input" title="input"></div>
                </td>
                <td width="50%"">
                    <div id="output" title="output"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```