# Is is possible to make element with % set dimensions to show scrolls, instead of increasing own size?

Tags: html, css, scroll, containers

For example, I have an element-container with dimensions `width: 100%;` and `height: 100%;` and `overflow: auto;`

When I adding inside it more elements, so those becomes too big for container, it increases own area to fit those, instead of showing scrolls.

Is there any solution for this?

Example:

```
<html style = 'height: 100%;'>
    <head>
        <title>test scrolls</title>
    </head>
    <body style = 'height: 100%;'>
        <table border = '1' style = 'width: 100%; height: 100%;'>
            <tr><td id = "test_td" height = '50%' style = 'overflow: scroll;'></td></tr>
            <tr><td height = '50%'><input type = "button" value = "add a lto of junk in first td" onclick = "document.getElementById('test_td').innerHTML = 'asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />'" /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ok, another example with div:

```
<html style = 'height: 100%;'>
    <head>
        <title>test scrolls</title>
    </head>
    <body style = 'height: 100%;'>
        <table border = '1' style = 'width: 100%; height: 100%;'>
            <tr><td height = '50%'><div id = "test_div" style = 'width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: scroll;'></div></td></tr>
            <tr><td height = '50%'><input type = "button" value = "add a lot of junk in div in first td" onclick = "document.getElementById('test_div').innerHTML = 'asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />'" /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please supply the code you have or create a fiddle.

Comment: please show us some code, and provide a JSFiddle link with a working demo

Comment: You can do it with javascript... I think its the only way...

Comment: @Gezzasa - I added the example.

Comment: @pomeh - I added the example.

Comment: `overflow` on a table's elements won't work as you expect: this is not supported. I have no real answer for you but you can Google for it specifically ("html table td scroll")(or look this http://stackoverflow.com/q/1211309/827168 and this http://stackoverflow.com/q/14136076/827168)

Comment: @pomeh - Ok, I added div into that TD. Shouldn't it work now? But it not work.

Comment: @Kosmos Check my answer. I only saw after posting that you wanted the heights at percentages

Comment: @Kosmos I managed to do it without JS ;). Only css. Check the bottom of my answer

Comment: @Gezzasa - Hm, are you sure that you pasted right example? I tested it and the div just changes own size instead of keeping it and showing the scroll. Also, it visually looks like mine own from main question.

Comment: @Kosmos did you check this one http://jsfiddle.net/pwcd9cxe/3/ and which example are you refering to? Your original question or the answer that you have posted? If you are refering to your answer down below, I have done it without using any JS.

Comment: @Gezzasa - Meh, this is my bad. I read your comment here, scrolled up by thinking it's your answer and copied my own last example from question :D Now I looked at your solution... Well, it's all good unless I want to place all that into other html tags. `position: absolute;` should be the huge problem.

Comment: @Kosmos that is funny xD. It will be fine if you have the Parent div/container set to position: relative; Then it will work perfectly.

Comment: Oh, huh. This is really works when placed into divs only, without tables. Well, ok. I guess I need to change a lot of something. Thank you for showing me all that.

Comment: My Pleasure. Try to avoid tables unless you have actual tabular data that you need to display.

Comment: @Gezzasa - Ok, after being too stubborn, I were able to do the same with tables with my own example by using double div in TD :O, that I will include in my own asnwer. Thanks to your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for

TD's can not scroll, but you can have a div inside that does scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/b9kzbf8c/1/

```
div.scrollable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

<table border = '1' style = 'width: 100%; height: 100%;'>
    <tr style="height: 40px; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <td>
            <div class=scrollable>Some content with a scrollbar if it's too big for the cell
                Some content with a scrollbar if it's too big for the cell
                Some content with a scrollbar if it's too big for the cell
            </div>
        </td>
    <table>
```

**EDIT**

I have done it with jQuery too

http://jsfiddle.net/pwcd9cxe/2/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var equalHeights;

    resize = function(me){
        equalHeights = me;
        $('.td').height(($(equalHeights).height())/2);
    };

    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('.td').height(($(equalHeights).height())/2);
    });

    resize($(window));
</script>

<style>
    .td {overflow-y: scroll;}
</style>

<div class="td">
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
</div>
</div>
<div class="tr">
<div class="td">
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
    Some content here that is copy pasted to fill up space. <br />
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I have managed to do it without any JS.

http://jsfiddle.net/pwcd9cxe/3/

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand what your example shows. In ie 10 and opera 12.17 there are no scrolls. And, I don't know what that `<tr style="height: 40px;` is for.

Comment: Go look at the fiddle link. The style on the table row is to set a height so that the div can scroll when more content is put it.

Comment: Sorry, but once I remove fixed height, everything stops working. I need all sizes to be in %, but some container to show scroll at overflow, instead of increasing own size.

Comment: Do you need to use tables?

Comment: Kinda yes. They are everywhere. With those is much easer to created needed for me layout; I though about possible solution. To place absolutely positioned div into TD. That div should have `overflow: scroll;` and dimensions in %. The problem is that % sizes doesn't work in such way and div stays slim. So, I currently writing recursive functions that would work every 0.5 seconds and fix size for divs based on it's parent sizes.

Comment: If you set all the heights to percentages it will go on for as long as you put in content without scrolling ever coming up. That is how percentages work. somewhere you will need to set a height.

Comment: I solved it with JS, you can look at my own answer, but I will wait for some better solution :P Thank you for noticing and trying to solve my problem.

Comment: Ok, even through I don't use jQuery, you has provided the solution for my problem. Thank you. Through, I still hope for no code solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/83akmom1/

You need to set the height of the parent of the div you are setting to `height: 100%;` and it will work

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrap{
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you say what's wrong with my example? It has height set everywhere, but no scrolls appears

Comment: You want the scroll to show just for the first tr element?

Comment: I want to make first TD to show scroll when content is to big to fit. And this is only example. I need general solution.

Comment: @Kosmos see my comment above

Answer (score 0):

```
<html style = 'height: 100%;'>
    <head>
        <title>test scrolls</title>

        <script type = "text/JavaScript">
            function endsWith(str, suffix)
            {
                if (!str)
                    return false;

                return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) >= 0;
            }

            function fixDimensionsRecursiveIn(start_elem)
            {
                if (!document || !document.body)
                    return;

                var curr_elem = start_elem ? start_elem : document.body;

                var pos = curr_elem.style.position || curr_elem.style.getAttribute("position");

                if (pos == "absolute")
                {
                    var curr_w = curr_elem.width || curr_elem.style.width;
                    var curr_h = curr_elem.height || curr_elem.style.height;
                    var parent_w = curr_elem.parentNode.clientWidth || curr_elem.parentNode.offsetWidth;
                    var parent_h = curr_elem.parentNode.clientHeight || curr_elem.parentNode.offsetHeight;

                    var w_fixed = false;
                    var h_fixed = false;

                    if (endsWith(curr_w, "%") && parent_w > 0)
                    {
                        curr_elem.original_width = curr_w;
                        curr_w = curr_w.substr(0, curr_w.length - 1);
                        curr_elem.style.width = ((curr_w * parent_w) / 100) + "px";

                        w_fixed = true;
                    }

                    if (endsWith(curr_h, "%") && parent_h > 0)
                    {
                        curr_elem.original_height = curr_h;
                        curr_h = curr_h.substr(0, curr_h.length - 1);
                        curr_elem.style.height = ((curr_h * parent_h) / 100) + "px";

                        h_fixed = true;
                    }

                    var possible_original_width = curr_elem.original_width;
                    var possible_original_height = curr_elem.original_height;

                    if (!w_fixed && endsWith(possible_original_width, "%") && parent_w > 0)
                    {
                        possible_original_width = possible_original_width.substr(0, possible_original_width.length - 1);
                        curr_elem.style.width = ((possible_original_width * parent_w) / 100) + "px";
                    }

                    if (!h_fixed && endsWith(possible_original_height, "%") && parent_h > 0)
                    {
                        possible_original_height = possible_original_height.substr(0, possible_original_height.length - 1);
                        curr_elem.style.height = ((possible_original_height * parent_h) / 100) + "px";
                    }
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < curr_elem.children.length; i++)
                    fixDimensionsRecursiveIn(curr_elem.children[i]);
            }

            setInterval(fixDimensionsRecursiveIn, 500);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style = 'height: 100%;'>
        <table border = '1' style = 'width: 100%; height: 100%;'>
            <tr><td height = '50%' style = 'position: relative;'><div id = "test_div" style = 'border: dashed; margin: 0px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: scroll;'></div></td></tr>
            <tr><td height = '50%'><input type = "button" value = "add a lot of junk in div in first td" onclick = "document.getElementById('test_div').innerHTML = 'asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />'" /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my own solution, but I hope to get some better solution in future.

Or that way by double div, based on Gezzasa's solution:

```
<html style = 'height: 100%;'>
    <head>
        <title>test scrolls</title>
    </head>
    <body style = 'height: 100%;'>
        <table border = '1' style = 'width: 100%; height: 100%;'>
            <tr>
                <td height = '50%'>
                <div  style = "border: solid; position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                    <div id = "test_div" style = 'border: dashed; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0%; width: 100%; overflow: scroll;'></div>
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height = '50%'>
                    <input type = "button" value = "add a lot of junk in div in first td" onclick = "document.getElementById('test_div').innerHTML = 'asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />asd<br />'" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery was a bit easier.