# Setting the width and ellipsis to the <td> element of a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am having table in which text inside the td's are of different length. I want to give fixed width to the td elements and the use `text-overflow: ellipsis` on the td elements, so that the whole text would not be shown. I have tried different ways but nothing works, please somebody help me with how I can achieve this.

```html
  <table>
     <tr>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>link</th>
        <th>description</th>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>condition</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>availability</th>
        <th>image_link</th>
        <th>Shipping</th>
        <th>"shipping weight"</th>
        <th>gtin</th>
        <th>brand</th>
        <th>mpn</th>
        <th>google_product_category</th>
        <th>product_type</th>
        <th>additional_image_link</th>
        <th>color</th>
        <th>size</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>age_group</th>
        <th>item_group_id</th>
        <th>sale_price</th>
        <th>"sale price effective date"</th>
        <th>size_type</th>
        <th>size_system</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>"Metallic turquoise leather envelope clutch"</td>
        <td style="width: 200px">https://www.runway2street.com/bags/clutch-bags/metallic-turquoise-leather-envelope-clutch</td>
        <td>" This elegant jeweltoned metallic leather envelope clutch with wrist strap is perfect for a fancy night out! It has a natural cork trim, magnetic closure and a zipper pocket on the inside to fit a cell phone. All accessories and hardware on the bag are gold plated.  Material: 100 leather, goldplated hardwareCountry of manufacture: Lebanon  "</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>new</td>
        <td>"370 USD"</td>
        <td>"in stock"</td>
        <td>http://az697095.vo.msecnd.net/vnext/products/3/12/Anja_Not-for-the-shy_accessories_bags_clutches_Turquoise-Cork_Metallic-turquoise-leather-envelope-clutch_38_320x480_v3.jpg</td>
        <td>"US::Standard Free Shipping: 47 USD"</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Anja</td>
        <td>FALSE</td>
        <td>"Apparel &amp; Accessories &gt; Handbags, Wallets &amp; Cases &gt; Handbags &gt; Clutches &amp; Special Occasion Bags"</td>
        <td>"Clutch Bags"</td>
        <td>http://az697095.vo.msecnd.net/vnext/products/3/12/Anja_Not-for-the-shy_accessories_bags_clutches_Turquoise-Cork_Metallic-turquoise-leather-envelope-clutch_35_320x480_v3.jpg</td>
        <td>Turquoise/Cork</td>
        <td>"One size"</td>
        <td>Female</td>
        <td>Adult</td>
        <td>ANJAFW12mec.ct</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Regular</td>
        <td>US</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: please add your css code or take a look at: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: Hello @yasar please read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136076/scroll-bar-for-a-table-cell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this css rule

```
table td {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Note: use **max-width** and not **width**

Edit: [JS-Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/dsupreme/dv4u2t56/1/)

Comment: Use min-width and max-width in combination.. Just using width doesn't work. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @MrLister you are also right. Your think a solution same as your solution so I couldn't post this.

Comment: @AvanishKumar Sorry?

Answer (score 1):

```
th,td
{
max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
```

this will work

Answer (score 0):

Styling table cells has always been problematic.

The most reliable way currently is to add container blocks in each of the cells and to style those.

```css
div.c {
  width:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>title</th>
    <th>link</th>
    <th>description</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>condition</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>availability</th>
    <th>image_link</th>
    <th>Shipping</th>
    <th>"shipping weight"</th>
    <th>gtin</th>
    <th>brand</th>
    <th>mpn</th>
    <th>google_product_category</th>
    <th>product_type</th>
    <th>additional_image_link</th>
    <th>color</th>
    <th>size</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>age_group</th>
    <th>item_group_id</th>
    <th>sale_price</th>
    <th>"sale price effective date"</th>
    <th>size_type</th>
    <th>size_system</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="c">"Metallic turquoise leather envelope clutch"</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">https://www.runway2street.com/bags/clutch-bags/metallic-turquoise-leather-envelope-clutch</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">" This elegant jeweltoned metallic leather envelope clutch with wrist strap is perfect for a fancy night out! It has a natural cork trim, magnetic closure and a zipper pocket on the inside to fit a cell phone. All accessories and hardware on the bag
      are gold plated. Material: 100 leather, goldplated hardwareCountry of manufacture: Lebanon "</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">4</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">new</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">"370 USD"</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">"in stock"</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">http://az697095.vo.msecnd.net/vnext/products/3/12/Anja_Not-for-the-shy_accessories_bags_clutches_Turquoise-Cork_Metallic-turquoise-leather-envelope-clutch_38_320x480_v3.jpg</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">"US::Standard Free Shipping: 47 USD"</div></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><div class="c">Anja</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">FALSE</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">"Apparel &amp; Accessories &gt; Handbags, Wallets &amp; Cases &gt; Handbags &gt; Clutches &amp; Special Occasion Bags"</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">"Clutch Bags"</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">http://az697095.vo.msecnd.net/vnext/products/3/12/Anja_Not-for-the-shy_accessories_bags_clutches_Turquoise-Cork_Metallic-turquoise-leather-envelope-clutch_35_320x480_v3.jpg</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">Turquoise/Cork</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">"One size"</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">Female</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">Adult</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">ANJAFW12mec.ct</div></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><div class="c">Regular</div></td>
    <td><div class="c">US</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```