# How to set row height or max row height of a table row

Tags: css, elementor

Below is an excerpt from a plugin on my elementor website. I've only included the body, tr, and td tags but please assume that everything else for a table is in place. I am trying to set a max row height on the table row and for the cells with overflow enable vertical scrolling. Currently, so the text doesn't grow the cell height, I have it set to white-space: nowrap; (see image below code). I have tried setting a height and a max-height for the table, tbody, tablesome__tbody class, tablesome__row class, tablesome__cell class, the table row itself, and on the td. I am certain my css rules are being applied because in Firefox developer tools I can see them as being active but the height is not what I set it to.

TL;DR -> I need help setting a row height or max row height so that my table cells do not grow vertically with content. Instead I would like the cell to scroll if there is too much content.

```
<tbody class="tablesome__tbody">
 <tr class="tablesome__row" data-state-record-id="1"> 
  <td style="--text-color: #ffffff; --background-color: #9696eb;" tabindex="0" class="tablesome__cell tablesome__cell--text" data-label="Name">skylar</td> 
  <td style="--text-color: #ffffff; --background-color: #9696eb;" tabindex="0" class="tablesome__cell tablesome__cell--text" data-label="Email">skylar@hennig.ame.com</td> 
  <td style="--text-color: #ffffff; --background-color: #9696eb;" tabindex="0" class="tablesome__cell tablesome__cell--text" data-label="Primary Market A">OEMs</td> 
  <td style="--text-color: #ffffff; --background-color: #9696eb;" tabindex="0" class="tablesome__cell tablesome__cell--text" data-label="Primary Market B">End Users</td> 
  <td style="--text-color: #ffffff; --background-color: #9696eb;" tabindex="0" class="tablesome__cell tablesome__cell--text" data-label="Primary Market C">integrated suppliers</td> 
  <td style="--text-color: #ffffff; --background-color: #9696eb;" tabindex="0" class="tablesome__cell tablesome__cell--text" data-label="Primary Markey D">machine tool distributors</td> 
  <td style="--text-color: #ffffff; --background-color: #9696eb;" tabindex="0" class="tablesome__cell tablesome__cell--text" data-label="Price, delivery and performance requirements, in that order?">OEMs</td> 
  <td style="--text-color: #ffffff; --background-color: #9696eb;" tabindex="0" class="tablesome__cell tablesome__cell--textarea" data-label="Why that focus?"><div class="ql-editor">Competitive market, so need to be price conscience of what makes up their machine.</div></td> 
  <td style="--text-color: #ffffff; --background-color: #9696eb;" tabindex="0" class="tablesome__cell tablesome__cell--text" data-label="Natural focus for our QROC program?">end user</td> 
  <td style="--text-color: #ffffff; --background-color: #9696eb;" tabindex="0" class="tablesome__cell tablesome__cell--textarea" data-label="Why does QROC satisfy their needs?"><div class="ql-editor">Quick reaction time</div></td> 
  <td style="--text-color: #ffffff; --background-color: #9696eb;" tabindex="0" class="tablesome__cell tablesome__cell--text" data-label="Challenge to receive info, Market A?">Integrated Supplier</td> 
  <td style="--text-color: #ffffff; --background-color: #9696eb;" tabindex="0" class="tablesome__cell tablesome__cell--text" data-label="Challenge to receive info, Market B?">Machine Tool Distributor</td> 
  <td style="--text-color: #ffffff; --background-color: #9696eb;" tabindex="0" class="tablesome__cell tablesome__cell--textarea" data-label="Why are they challenging?"><div class="ql-editor">Hand measuring is needed and hard to get accurate drawings.</div></td> 
  <td style="--text-color: #ffffff; --background-color: #9696eb;" tabindex="0" class="tablesome__cell tablesome__cell--textarea" data-label="How can you help?"><div class="ql-editor">Fill out the data sheets, pictures, and provide as much detail on application, chip type, competitive detail, and machine type as possible.</div></td> 
  <td style="--text-color: #ffffff; --background-color: #9696eb;" tabindex="0" class="tablesome__cell tablesome__cell--text" data-label="Elevator Pitch">Fives G&amp;L I know we've had our history together, both good and bad, with many different Hennig and AME products over the years at your location, and other Fives facilities across North America. While we have continued to provide excellent products and services in some areas, we've needed to make a lot of improvements in others. Of course we do understand we've got our work cut out for ourselves to compete with the strong relationships you've formed with your current vendors, we believe we're more than capable for stepping up to the occasion. Over the past few years we've made considerable efforts to improve our quality, reputation, and manufacturing resources to compete with anyone in the market. We relish the opportunity to quote any upcoming components or systems, and appreciate any insight on how we can better serve you moving forward. Perhaps we can arrange a day in the near future to host you for lunch and a tour of our facility.</td> 
  <td style="--text-color: #ffffff; --background-color: #9696eb;" tabindex="0" class="tablesome__cell tablesome__cell--date" data-label="Submission Date">August 30, 2022</td> 
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

### This is currently what I am seeing in my table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can force the relevant table cells to be inline block as follows but beware it also causes a bunch of unwanted side effects e.g. text not centering, table cell sizes not being responsive etc. It's be safer to wrap them in a div as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136076/scroll-bar-for-a-table-cell%20%20AFAIK%20table%20cells%20don%27t%20use%20the%20overflow%20property.) but it can work

```css
table {
  width:300px;
}

td:last-child {
  padding:0.25rem;
  max-height:30px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Col1</td>
    <td>Col2</td>
    <td>Lorum ipsum yadda ydadda yadda etc this is what I want to scroll and more info here too</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Col1</td>
    <td>Col2</td>
    <td>Lorum ipsum jibber jabber etc and this one too. Lots of info here as well</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```